# Retain select tag value if user doesn't confirm dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The ajax is fired when user confirms, but if user cancels the confirm dialog still the select tag value changes though ajax isn't fired. I want something like if user cancels then select tag should retain it's previous value. I have this:

```
<select name="ss" id="<?=$row['id'];?>" onchange="_changeStatus(this.value,'<?=$row['id'];?>');">
   <option value='Paid'>Paid</option>
   <option value='Verified'>Verified</option>
   <option value='Inprocess'>Inprocess</option>
   <option value='Chargeback'>Chargeback</option>
</select>
```

script:

```
function _changeStatus(v,i){
       if(confirm("Sure to Update")){
       $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'change-status.php',
            data: {val:v,eid:i,actionid:1},
            success: function (res) {
              if(res!="scr"){
                alert("Unexpected Error, Page will be refreshed !");
                window.location.reload();
              }

            }
          });
     }
    }
```

Comment: else $("#id_of_select").val(v);

Comment: @ParthShah not really

Comment: v variable has new value stored in it

Comment: Create a new global variable to store the old value of the select. Update it to the new value after the ajax, or reset the select to the old value in an `else` on the confirm.

Comment: no need to go with global variable imo... better to keep it as attr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like that:

```
<select defaultValue="Paid" name="ss" id="<?=$row['id'];?>" onchange="_changeStatus(this,'<?=$row['id'];?>');">
   <option value='Paid'>Paid</option>
   <option value='Verified'>Verified</option>
   <option value='Inprocess'>Inprocess</option>
   <option value='Chargeback'>Chargeback</option>
</select>
```

---

```
function _changeStatus(vobj,i){
    var v = vobj.value;
    if($(vobj).attr('value_before')){
        var vbefore = $(vobj).attr('value_before');
    }else{
        var vbefore = vobj.defaultValue;
    }
    if(confirm("Sure to Update")){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'change-status.php',
            data: {val:v,eid:i,actionid:1},
            success: function (res){
                if(res!="scr"){
                    alert("Unexpected Error, Page will be refreshed !");
                    window.location.reload();
                }else{
                    $(vobj).attr('value_before',v);
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        $(vobj).val(vbefore);
    }
}
```

---

Please note that I have left it as similar as possible, so you would get a concept. Generally it's not a good practice to bind events inline when using jQuery, as well as mixing javascript with jQuery if not necessary.

Comment: there's no attribute like `value_before`

Comment: Oh sorry... missed `$`, fixed... `value_before` is an artificial attribute to keep previous value... if it's not yet defined, as there was no previous value, it defaults to selects default value. Please note that `onchange` value have changed as well.

Comment: well somewhat worked ! but the select tag value gets blank instead of previous value

Comment: you probably need to define defaultValue... `<select defaultValue="Paid" name="ss" id="<?=$row['id'];?>" onchange="_changeStatus(this,'<?=$row['id'];?>');">` or if not, just don't use defaultValue, but change `var vbefore = vobj.defaultValue;` to fixed `var vbefore = "Paid"`